# what is the meaning of this sentence ?.

Tags: linear-algebra

Im sorry ,my english is weak

After  reading this [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/344388/557708),some  doubt regarding language  has been arise in my mind given below

what is the meaning of this sentence

Let $A_{ij}$ be the $m \times n$ matrix whose entries are all zero except for the entry $ \{i,j\}$ which is one

My attempt :Im thinking like this , take $ m=2 , n=3$  Now \begin{bmatrix} 0&1&1\\1&0&1\end{bmatrix}

for $m=n=2$\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}

Is its correct ?

Comment: Purely from the sentence above, it seems like it means that if $m=2$, $n=3$, then one has 6 matrices which are given by $$A_{11}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},$$ $$A_{12}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0& 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},$$ ... $$A_{23}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0& 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: oks got it now @projectilemotion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, they mean that all entries in the matrix are zeros, except for one *single* entry, given by the pair $(i,j)$. For example, $m=3, n=4, i=2, j=1$ you would have the matrix like this:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Note it is an $m\times n=3\times 4$ matrix, and only the entry $A_{ij}=A_{21}$ is equal to $1$.

Comment: thanks u @stinking Bishop